# Why doesn't this object work in width method of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following works:

```js
$(".images").attr("width", ($(this).attr("data-asp") * 50) );
```

```css
img {
 height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="images" data-asp="0.75" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a4d2d16b0d988f98779e2737559ef22?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
<img class="images" data-asp="1.33" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a4d2d16b0d988f98779e2737559ef22?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
<img class="images" data-asp="1" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a4d2d16b0d988f98779e2737559ef22?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

`this` is in `$(".images").attr("width", $(this).height());`

But `this` in the following don't work:

```js
$(".images").width(50 * $(this).attr("data-asp"));
```

```css
img {
height: 20px;
width: auto;  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="images" data-asp="0.75"  src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a4d2d16b0d988f98779e2737559ef22?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
<img class="images" data-asp="1.33" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a4d2d16b0d988f98779e2737559ef22?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
<img class="images" data-asp="1" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a4d2d16b0d988f98779e2737559ef22?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

```
`this` is in `$(".images").width($(this).height());`
```

Why doesn't `this` work in width method of jquery while it works in other methods?

Comment: I think we need more context....

Comment: Seems like it is working now. I have to recheck my actual website where it is not working.

Comment: hmm.. It is still not working in actual website. Let me replicate the exact code.

Comment: FYI `$(".images").attr("width", $(this).height())` actually doesnt work.. if you replace `attr` with `css` you will see the changes applied. So what you claim is working is `Not Working` and what you claim not working is `Working`

Comment: Your updated code makes less sense since `this` is window...

Comment: And with that edit is worse.... You are now reading a data attribute and setting all the images to that attribute... So whatever the last one is will set the width of all of them.... and `this` is still the window.

Comment: just check in you website code that where are you executing these lines? Try to console.log value of this .

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Why wouldn't `.attr("width", val)` work exactly? https://jsfiddle.net/ft40eyr5/1/

Comment: @Deep Would console log work in jquery attr and width methods?

Comment: @epascarello The first example of `this` in attr used to work in my website code. But it is not working now. May be I got dilluded.

Comment: you can console.log the value of this just before these lines of code

Comment: @Deep I have added console.log in second example but this is giving weird error.

Comment: @user31782  i meant it like console.log(this); $(".images").width( 50 * $(this).attr("data-asp")); and in your website code. Check the answer below $(this) inside the .each loop value on images will be a img element.

Comment: @Deep Then `that` is simply the `window` object.

Comment: @Santi I know it must work... But in this case it is not working that's what I wanted to say.. Even I don't know why it didn't work here..

Answer (score 1):

How you are trying to read the attribute for the element is flawed. You need to loop over the collection and set each one individually.

```
$(".images").each( function () {
    var img = $(this);
    img.width(50 * img.data("asp"));
});
```

Comment: Another solution is `$(".images").width(function(){retutn 50 * $(this).attr("data-asp") })` -- this is working perfectly in my website.